# Find stops after the first file

Tags: json, node.js, linux, bash

Please help me understand why ncu is causing a `find` operation to stop after the first file?  I have 25 project folders, all with their own `package.json` and `bower.json` file (not all have `bower.json`).

Issuing this command with an `echo` works perfectly:

```
find ../ -name "package.json" -type f -exec echo '{}' +
```

... all files are printed to the screen.

However, this syntax stops after the first file when I use ncu:

```
find ../ -name "package.json" -type f -exec ncu -u -a --packageFile '{}' +
```

Here's the only output of the command:

```
$ find ../ -name "package.json" -type f -exec ncu -u -a --silent --packageFile '{}' +
Using /home/joeblow/projects/app01/package.json
[..................] - :
All dependencies match the latest package versions :)
```

The versions I'm using is:

```
bash version: 4.3.42(1)-release
find version: 4.7.0-git
node version: 6.9.4
npm version: 4.1.2
npm-check-updates version: 2.8.9
```

Comment: Does `ncu` support multiple files on a single command line? If not, use `\;` instead of `+`

Comment: That was it!  I assumed ncu would have given an error if the arguments were wrong.  Guess not.

Answer (score 0):

`ncu` (aka `npm-check-updates`) silently ignores all but the first file.

Use `-exec ncu -u -a --packageFile '{}' \;` instead to only run it with a single file at a time.